# Improving Amazon SQS Performance

Tags: node.js, multithreading, amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

Everything I can find about performance of Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS), including their own documentation, suggests that getting high throughput requires multiple threads. And I've verified this myself using the JS API with Node 12. If I create multiple threads, I get about the same throughput on each thread, so the total throughput increase is pretty much linear. But I'm running this on a nice machine with lots of cores. When I run in Lambda on a single core, multiple threads don't improve the performance, and generally this is what I would expect of multi-threaded apps.

But here's what I don't understand - there should be very little going on here in the way of CPU, most of the time is spent waiting on web requests. The AWS SQS API appears to be asynchronous in that all of the methods use callbacks for the responses, and I'm using Promises to "asyncify" all of the API calls, with multiple tasks running concurrently. Normally doing this with any kind of async IO is handled great by Node, and improves throughput hugely, I do it all the time with database APIs, multiple streams, etc. But SQS definitely isn't behaving that way, it's behaving as though its IO is actually synchronous and blocking threads on the network calls, which would be outrageous for any modern API.

Has anyone had success getting high SQS message throughput in a single Node thread? The max I'm seeing is about 50 to 100 messages/sec for FIFO queues (send, receive, and delete, all of which are calling the batch methods with the max batch size of 10). And this is running in lambda, i.e. on their own network, which is only slightly faster than running it on my laptop over the Internet, another surprising find. [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-throughput-horizontal-scaling-and-batching.html) says FIFO queues should support up to 3000 messages per second when batching, which would be just fine for me. Does it really take multiple threads on multiple cores or virtual CPUs to achieve this? That would be ridiculous, I just can't believe that much CPU would be used, it should be mostly IO time, which should be asynchronous.

**Edit:**

As I continued to test, I found that the linear improvement with the number of threads only happened when each thread was processing a different queue. If the threads are all processing the same queue, there is no improvement by adding threads. So it behaves as though each queue is throttled by Amazon. But the throughput to which it seems to be throttling is way below what I found documented as the max throughput. Really confused and disappointed right now!

Comment: You're driving messages into the FIFO queue at a high enough rate, or it's already populated with enough messages, to test this presumably. Also note the comments on that doc page indicating "the maximum throughput from a single thread over a single connection averages 50 TPS" if latency averages 20ms.

Comment: @jarmod yes, the producer rate is normally a lot higher, but I've tried both running the producers and consumers concurrently and doing all the sends before starting the consumers. I do see the comment you're referring to now, I suppose that's what I'm running up against. I'm just not real happy about their explanation of needing more threads because each thread waits on a web request/response. Threads are expensive, I don't understand why any modern API would block threads waiting for web requests to respond instead of making multiple concurrent, async requests on the same thread.

Comment: @reads0520 the documentation is using "threads" in a very casual/imprecise sense, referring to the number of distinct consumers that don't block each other (in the consumer-side code), whether that's because of multiple processes, multiple threads, or the concurrency allowed by firing off multiple async requests... but unless you are using different MessageGroupIDs, FIFO queues are constrained by the strict ordering of messages -- consumer 2 will receive no messages until consumer 1 processes what it already received and deletes those messages... else you aren't getting strict ordering.

Comment: @Michael thanks, that makes perfect sense! I'll answer the question based on your comments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michael's comments to the original question were right on. I was sending all messages to the same message group. I had previously been working with AMQP message queues, in which messages will be ordered in the queue in the order they're sent, and they'll be distributed to subscribers in that order. But when multiple listeners are consuming the AMQP queue, because of varying network latencies, there is no guarantee that they'll be received in that order chronologically.

So that's actually a really cool feature of SQS, the guarantee that messages will be chronologically received in the order they were sent within the same message group. In my case, I don't care about the receipt order. So now I'm setting a unique message group ID on each message, and scaling up performance by increasing the number of async message receive loops, still just in one thread, and the throughput is amazing!

**So the bottom line**: If exact receipt order of messages isn't important for your FIFO queue, set the message group ID to a unique value on each message, and scale out with more receiver tasks to get the best throughput performance. If you do need guaranteed message ordering, it looks like around 50 messages per second is about the best you'll do.

Comment: This helps. A very related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66861646/throughput-in-standard-sqs-vs-fifo-sqs-with-a-unique-groupid-for-every-message Could you have a look at it please?